# Auto with uniform initialization expands to unexpected type

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, auto, uniform-initialization

Consider this short program compiled with GCC 4.7.2 `g++ -std=c++11 test.cc`

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>

struct type{
  type(int a) : v(a) {}
  int v;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<type> type_ptr;

int main(){
  int value = 3;
  std::queue<type_ptr> queue;
  auto ptr{std::make_shared<type>(value)};
  queue.push(ptr);
}
```

The compiler outputs the following errors:

```
src/test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
src/test.cc:15:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue<std::shared_ptr<type> >::push(std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<type> >&)’
src/test.cc:15:17: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/queue:65:0,
                 from src/test.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:211:7: note: void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<type>; _Sequence = std::deque<std::shared_ptr<type>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<type> > >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = std::shared_ptr<type>]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<type> >’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const std::shared_ptr<type>&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:216:7: note: void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::shared_ptr<type>; _Sequence = std::deque<std::shared_ptr<type>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<type> > >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = std::shared_ptr<type>]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:216:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<type> >’ to ‘std::queue<std::shared_ptr<type> >::value_type&& {aka std::shared_ptr<type>&&}’
```

Indicating that the auto type is expanded to an initializer list instead of `std::shared_ptr<type>`; in fact replacing `{...}` with `= ...` makes the code compile as auto expands to the correct type.

I'm a bit suprised that this seemingly obvious use case fails to achieve the expected result. Especially as I recall the new bracket initialization syntax to be touted as the end-all, be-all solution to initializing problems.

So my question is: Was this intended in the standard? Or is it an oversight or even a gcc bug? Or am I just thinking about it wrong?

Comment: This is standard behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Xeo says in his comment, this is standard behavior. **7.1.6.4 auto specifier [dcl.spec.auto]** para 6 specifies:

> Once the type of a *declarator-id* has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable using the *declarator-id* is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument deduction. Let `T` be the type that has been determined for a variable identifier `d`. Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initializer is a *braced-init-list* (8.5.4), with `std::initializer_list<U>`. The type deduced for the variable `d` is then the deduced `A` determined using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a function template parameter type and the initializer for `d` is the corresponding argument. If
>   the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed.

It is also widely despised - there's a [proposal under review by the committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) to change the behavior for C++14. C++14's support for generalized lambda capture [exacerbates the problem](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/std-proposals/brace-intialization/std-proposals/YTti2Vy1LGM/Z02smt4udEEJ).

Update: In Urbana (See CWG Motion 16 in [N4251 WG21 2014-11 Urbana Minutes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html)) the committee applied [N3922 New Rules for auto deduction from braced-init-list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) to the C++17 Working Paper. They decided to fix the special case that allows `auto` to deduce an `initializer_list` by adding **another** special case. `auto` works the same way for *copy-list-initialization*, but for *direct-list-initialization* from a *braced-init-list* with a single element `auto` deduces from that element directly. *direct-list-initialization* from a multiple-element *braced-init-list* is now ill-formed.

That means that given

```
auto x = {42};
```

`x` has type `std::initializer_list<int>`, but in

```
auto x{42};
```

`x` is an `int`.

Comment: Thank you, accepted answer. I'll just go back to plain style initialization unless I explicitly need uniform initialization to avoid future problems.

Comment: What is the final status on this matter?

Comment: @Etherealone Updated the answer to reflect changes to the C++ Working Paper applied at the Urbana meeting in November 2014.